# Neo4j's NPM component blows up without error

Tags: node.js, neo4j

I'm using the *thingdom/node-neo4j* module like this:

```
var neo = require('neo4j');
var db = new new.GraphDatabase(...);
```

but when I call the `cypher` method with some invalid script, instead of returning an error (allowing me to handle it), it blows up:

```
db.cypher('// invalid cypher script', (err, res) => {
    if (err) console.log('ERROR: ' + err);
    console.log(res);
})
```

what I get is a stack trace that looks like this:

> /Users/ekkis/dev/test/inc/node_modules/neo4j/lib-new/errors.js:20
>         Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);
>               ^
>
> TypeError: Error.captureStackTrace is not a function
>       at ClientError.Error [as constructor] (/Users/ekkis/dev/test/inc/node_modules/neo4j/lib-new/errors.js:20:13)
>       at new ClientError (/Users/ekkis/dev/test/inc/node_modules/neo4j/lib-new/errors.js:81:48)
>       at Function.__dirname.Error.Error._fromObject (/Users/ekkis/dev/test/inc/node_modules/neo4j/lib-new/errors.js:70:14)
>       at /Users/ekkis/dev/test/inc/node_modules/neo4j/lib-new/GraphDatabase.js:302:25
>       at Request._callback (/Users/ekkis/dev/test/inc/node_modules/neo4j/lib-new/GraphDatabase.js:92:20)
>       at Request.self.callback (/Users/ekkis/dev/test/inc/node_modules/request/request.js:187:22)
>       at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
>       at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)
>       at Request. (/Users/ekkis/dev/test/inc/node_modules/request/request.js:969:12)
>       at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
>       at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
>       at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)

I'm using node v7.3.0 and posted an issue with the maintainer here: https://github.com/thingdom/node-neo4j/issues/214 but so far no solution.  is anyone else running into this? any solutions?

Comment: Not a solution to your problem, but did you consider using the official Neo4j driver: https://www.npmjs.com/package/neo4j-driver ?

Comment: https://github.com/thingdom/node-neo4j/issues/211#issue-197061622

Comment: @WilliamLyon, yes, of course.  it's on my roadmap but won't probably happen for a bit

Comment: @stdob--, yes, I had referenced that posting in my own at github.  I know I'm not alone, just hoping has figured out a patch... no time now for that rabbit hole